# At which stage of rocket development does systems engineering become critical/useful?

Tags: launch, rockets, spacecraft-development, launch-vehicle, launch-system

Rockets are complicated system and the interaction of the sub-systems are even more complicated.

But different subsystems tend to be developed parallels without much interaction but does so when integrated.

Systems Engineering is *said* as the discipline that helps in this case.

At which point in the development cycle of a launch vehicle, does this systems engineering brings in substantial benefit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. Systems engineering means different things to different people, and the function isn't always explicitly called out.

Comment: I like this question but suggest it to be more specific. Systems engineering should be defined here.

Comment: @GdD As mentioned by rehctawrats I will try to add more content and elaborate on SE definition and try to make the  question more specific

Comment: A good way to proceed might be to explain what you are interested in, but ask for historical examples. For example: *"When was launch vehicle design first addressed from a systems engineering perspective?"* A link to some convenient definition of systems engineering that you are comfortable with would also help.

Comment: As you can see, the insta-closers don't believe that constructive comments are sufficient, and so would prefer to make more work for everyone else. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5lTA.png Your questions are great and you are very responsive, but some users will reflexively try to close and punish, rather than community build.

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for the constructive comments. I will be updating the question shortly. I am browsing for some support material.

Comment: It's not so much that this question is too broad (although it is), it's that it's too easily answered: From the very, very start. Any answer beyond this short and admittedly flippant answer would require books, and that's what makes it too broad.

Answer (score 7):

As someone who sometimes works professionally in this very field as a systems engineer, other times in more specific roles, the answer is easy: From the very start.